# Filling the grid View with more than 1 table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-express

I have the following code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString=@"Data Source=RITESH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;Integrated Security=true";
 con.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Employee2",con);
 SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from employee1", con);
 DataSet dst=new DataSet();
 DataTable dt= new DataTable();
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
```

Now please tell me how to show both the tables in 1 Gridview..

Comment: Use Union and bind correct column

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code ..

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection connection =
           new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter =
        new SqlDataAdapter ("select t1.* ,t2.* from table1 t1,table2 t2 ", connection);


    adapter.Fill(dataSet);
    MyGridview1.DataSource=dataSet;
    MyGridview1.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can also make use of [`Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to combine 2 DataTable like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=RITESH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;Integrated     Security=true";
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Employee2", con);
SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from employee1", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

adp.Fill(dt);
adp1.Fill(dt1);

//After merge u will get merge result in dt.
dt.Merge(dt1);
```

While merging DataTable make sure schema must match.